# FileSystemWatcher Changed event doesn't fire

Tags: c#, winforms

```
FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
fsw.Path = @"C:\foo.txt";
fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(LogFileChanged);

private void LogFileChanged(object s, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{ 

}
```

If i put a breakpoint in `LogFileChanged()` -> open and edit `foo.txt` -> saves the file, the breakpoint doesn't hit. Can someone explain what I missed?

Comment: where is the breakpoint?

Comment: @dtryon in the `LogFileChanged` method

Comment: Have you tried to add `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` instead of the breakpoint?  Might at least prove that it is not an attachment issue.

Comment: A good text editor never changes a file, that can cause irretrievable data loss.  Instead it writes a new file, renames the old file, renames the new file, deletes the old file.  No change event.

Comment: BTW, your `LogFileChanged()` method shouldn't `static` ? Because you can't access it from `FileSystemEventHandler` without defining its' class object.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that there is change event? Consider writing test program that actually explicitly open -> save -> close (instead of new -> save -> delete old/rename new sequence).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a file not a path

```
fsw.Path = @"C:\foo.txt";
```

you need to set

```
fsw.Path = @"C:\";
fsw.Filter = "foo.txt";
```

[Filter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Have you set this property?

```
 fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Comment: Yes I just added that, Im afraid it didnt help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @durron597 this is an answer.